# is apple store accept the app part of it depend on UI web view flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, uiwebview, app-store

recently I have been working on Flutter app and I read that the App Store will no longer accept any app that uses UI web view,
so here is my question what about if part of my app depends on UI web view?
is anyone tried to upload have the same scenario before

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Apple objects to apps that are just websites ported into an app through a webview. This is a violation of guideline:

"4.2 Minimum Functionality Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website...."



But in your case your app already has enough in it to pass this requirement, so adding a webview through webkit code should not raise this objection.

Comment: yes i read something like that before so i think i need someone who tried to use WebUI as a part of his application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after I deployed the app they accept it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).